# json-server does not use the code provided in the middleware file

Tags: node.js, json, express, json-server

I am using json-server to simulate some api calls responses for front-end development turns out that adding a middleware does not really work out in my case:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "concurrently -k \"json-server --watch api-faked/db.json --routes api-faked/routes.json --middlewares api-faked/middleware.js --ro\" \"vue-cli-service serve\"",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

When starting:

```
[1]  INFO  Starting development server...
[0]
[0]   \{^_^}/ hi!
[0]
[0]   Loading api-faked/db.json
[0]   Loading api-faked/routes.json
[0]   Loading api-faked/middleware.js
[0]   Done
[0]
```

It seems that the `middleware.js` is considered by json-server, however, a simple example such as the `middleware.js` like below:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('X-Hello', 'World')
    next()
}
```

Does not add any header to my response headers:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/operations/?code_like=adi
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2019 12:23:53 GMT
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Powered-By: Express
```

What am I missing here?

Side-note: actually removing the `next` from the `middleware.js` does not even alter anything, it's like even though the middlware has been added to the json-server configuration it seems not really run at any point in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution in my case was using the module style of json-server, which basically involves creating a `js` file and recreating router which is otherwise created automatically with the `db.json` and `routes.json`, unlike the automatic mode, it supports adding a middleware which can intercept pretty much everything.

Example

```
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const path = require('path');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const defaultMiddleware = jsonServer.defaults();

// It is recommended to use the bodyParser middleware before any other middleware in your application
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser);

server.use(defaultMiddleware);

// Define custom routes (routes.json)
const routes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'routes.json')));
server.use(jsonServer.rewriter(routes));

// Add custom middleware before JSON Server router
const customMiddleware = require(path.join(__dirname, 'middleware.js'));
server.use(customMiddleware);

// This is where `json-server`'s magic happens ;)
const router = jsonServer.router(path.join(__dirname, 'db.json'));

// Start the application by listening to port 3000,
// Although this won't print the nice starting message you see when
// running `json-server` as CLI command, it still runs the app correctly.
server.use(router);
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('JSON Server is running')
});
```

With the structure of the folder `api-faked` being:

- `server.js`
- `middleware.js`
- `db.json`
- `routes.json`

Instead of serving the application like that (in `package.json`):

`"serve": "concurrently -k \"json-server --watch api-faked/db.json --routes api-faked/routes.json --middlewares api-faked/middleware.js --ro\" \"vue-cli-service serve\"",`

it is now like this:

`"serve": "concurrently -k \"nodemon api-faked/server.js --watch api-faked/*.*\"`

I also use [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) which restart the json-server if any change occurs in any of the given files (ie. `--watch api-faked/*.*`)

I've been put on the right track thanks to the answer given in that [GitHub issue: json-server does not use the code provided in the middleware file](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/996)

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the actual call to tie/link the middleware to your express app. Try calling:

```
app.use(enter_middleware_function_here);
```

This is assuming you instantiated your app similar to:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
```